# My Fragment view not updating according to search data in SearchView - Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, searchview

It's working with initial value but not updating with searchview texts: 
File Fragment

```
class TripHome : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mTripViewModel: TripViewModel

    override fun onCreateView() {      
     //trimmed adapter initialize

        mTripViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TripViewModel::class.java)
        mTripViewModel.showTripData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { trip ->
            adapter.setData(trip)
        })

        view.fab_addTrip.setOnClickListener{
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_tripHome_to_tripAdd)
        }

        val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
        val search = menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
            override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
                // Add menu items
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.searchtrip, menu)

                val search = menu.findItem(R.id.searchItems)
                val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView
                searchView.isSubmitButtonEnabled = true
                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
                    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                        if (query != null) {
                            getItemsFromDb(query)
                        }
                        return true
                    }

                    override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
                        if (query != null) {
                            getItemsFromDb(query)
                        }
                        return true
                    }
            })
            }

            override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
                // Handle the menu selection
                return when (menuItem.itemId) {
                    R.id.searchItems -> {
                        // clearCompletedTasks()
                        true
                    }
                    else -> false
                }
            }
        }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)

        return view
    }
    private fun getItemsFromDb(searchText: String) {
        var searchText = searchText
        searchText = "%$searchText%"

        mTripViewModel.searchTrip(query = searchText).observe(this, Observer { trip->
            trip?.let {
                Log.e("List = ", trip.toString())
            }

        })

    }
}
```

My list adapter file

```
class TripList : RecyclerView.Adapter<TripList.MyViewHolder>() {
    private var tripList = emptyList<TripModel>()
    
    //trimmed onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder

    fun setData(trip: List<TripModel>){
        this.tripList = trip
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

I tested the search view and I got these detail in logcat, seem the search view worked but the view not filter

2022-11-06 21:09:05.090 9252-9252/com.example.newone E/List =: [TripModel(id=3, name=879, vehicle=qweqwe, date=12/12/4321, start=qewqe, to=sdadas, risk=fbcxvc, description=xcvsdfs)]

Can someone help me, I need the recyclerview could filter data, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are not updating your adapter after you filter:

```
private fun getItemsFromDb(searchText: String) {
        var searchText = searchText
        searchText = "%$searchText%"

        mTripViewModel.searchTrip(query = searchText).observe(this, Observer { trip->
            trip?.let {
                Log.e("List = ", trip.toString())
                // call this method again with new trip list
                adapter.setData(trip)
            }

        })

    }
```

Comment: If that helped please mark this answer as accepted for closure of the question.